# Explicit template instantiation and one definition rule

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, one-definition-rule

I'm using explicit template instantiation. As far as I understand, because I'm instantiating in the header file, the following example should violate the one definition rule. But not a single compiler I've tried has a problem with it. What am I missing? Why does this work? And is it guaranteed to work on every compiler?

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

template<class T>
struct A
{
    T x;
};

// instantiate
template struct A<int>;
template struct A<float>;
template struct A<double>;

#endif
```

file1.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

A<int> f();

int main()
{
    A<int> a = f();
}
```

file2.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

A<int> f()
{
    return A<int>();
}
```

Comment: Ill formed programs NDR (No diagnostic required) is allowed to not show error/warning.

Comment: @Jarod42 I see, so this is ill-formed, but it's just that no compiler complains? In other words, I need to fix it. Would sticking these instantiations inside a function declared inline be correct?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for the pointer. It's very helpful. But same question as to Jarod42.

Comment: The usual approach by the linker is to just pick one of the definitions and ignore the others.  If they're all the same you shouldn't have a problem.